# Collapsable Bootstrap Panel with Input group, making the whole heading clickable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add an `input-group` into a collapsable panel heading.
The panel body is collapsed using an `a` element, and I'd like the whole panel heading to be clickable, except for the `input-group`.

The following is what I've got so far. You'd notice two things:

1. The clickable area is only a narrow strip on the top of the heading.
2. The heading looks like a mess when the window is wide (Expand the snippet below, or see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xdh3gs88/) in a wide screen).

How can I solve these problems?

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
}

.panel-group .panel {
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.panel-default > .panel-heading {
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #212121;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    border-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.panel-title > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.more-less {
    float: left;
    color: #212121;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.panel-default > .panel-heading + .panel-collapse > .panel-body {
    border-top-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.input-group {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
                  <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                </a>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                           <option value="1">option 1</option>
                           <option value="2">option 2</option>
                           <option value="3">option 3</option>
                        </select>
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                           <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Add</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="panel-body">
               My Panel Body
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40079781/bootstrap-panel-with-input-group) is kind of a related question, but the OP (and the answers) uses a button to collapse the panel, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to improve your CSS codes:

```
.panel-title{
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.panel-title > a{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Full snippet:

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
}

.panel-group .panel {
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.panel-default > .panel-heading {
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #212121;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    border-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.panel-title{
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.panel-title > a {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.more-less {
    float: left;
    color: #212121;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.panel-default > .panel-heading + .panel-collapse > .panel-body {
    border-top-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.input-group {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
                  <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                </a>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                           <option value="1">option 1</option>
                           <option value="2">option 2</option>
                           <option value="3">option 3</option>
                        </select>
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                           <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Add</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="panel-body">
               My Panel Body
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Feel free to edit this to best fit your need.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work when displaying the panel in a wide screen. Try to insert a snippet (as I did in my question), and then click "Expand snippet" to open it in a wide screen.

Comment: @HeyJude thanks for edit. Of course it was just base solution. you need to do more things like z-index for add btn and other things. but generally it works.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
}

.panel-group .panel {
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.panel-default > .panel-heading {
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #212121;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    border-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.panel-title > a {

    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.panel-default > .panel-heading + .panel-collapse > .panel-body {
    border-top-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.input-group {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.btn-group{ padding-top: 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-title">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 btn-group">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" class="btn ">
                      <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                    </a>
                      <div class="input-group">
                          <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                             <option value="1">option 1</option>
                             <option value="2">option 2</option>
                             <option value="3">option 3</option>
                          </select>
                          <span class="input-group-btn">
                             <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" style="margin-right: 10px">Add</button>
                          </span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="panel-body">
               My Panel Body
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. However, the `select` shouldn't fill the whole heading when the screen is wide enough (You can see that in my original snippet, when expanded, it fills only part of the heading), and in that case - the whole heading should be clickable.